# TypeScript/Angular: Logging instance variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I'm learning to build Angular applications using TypeScript. During development, I've created a new object. The object's class contains a variable (setup) which i would like to log to the console in the joke.module.ts.

However, this is not working. The error I'm getting is: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.

Why is this, and how should I log this?

**joke.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'joke',
    templateUrl: './joke.component.html'
})
export class JokeComponent {
    setup: string;
    punchline: string;

    constructor() {
        this.setup = "What did the cheese say when it looked in the mirror?";
        this.punchline = "Halloumi (hello me)"
    }
}
```

**joke.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { JokeComponent } from './component/joke.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [JokeComponent],
    bootstrap: [JokeComponent]
})
export class JokeModule {
    joke = new JokeComponent();
    console.log(joke.setup); // error here
}
```

Comment: You cannot use console.log inside an ES6's class declaration. It should be inside a method.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler make an answer out of that

Comment: @ChristianBenseler, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are trying to write implementation directly in the class, rather than within a method:

```
export class JokeModule {
    private joke: JokeComponent;
    constructor() {
        this.joke = new JokeComponent();
        console.log(this.joke.setup); // error here
    }
}
```

Also, I'm looking for bonus points for that private joke.

Comment: `joke = new JokeComponent()` is a proper thing. console isn't.

Comment: Thank you Fenton, clear example. Got everything up and running!